# Python Shell Doesn't Work, Doesn't Run Interpreter (Flask)

Tags: python, shell, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been following along with Miguel Grinberg's Flask Web Development and hit a snag when trying to create database roles. The book suggests that I use the following command to run the shell and generate a python shell and create database roles:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdMx5.png

But when the identical command it doesn't give me a python shell that I can write commands into. It just starts the server and runs the program, leaving me unable to execute the commands I need to create database roles.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/czTqF.png

In both cases, hello.py is just a simple flask program with relevant database classes. Not sure why this is happening. I've activated the virtual environment and done everything as described in the text. Any thoughts?

Here is the entirety of the code in hello.py

```
    # imports
    from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask import Flask, render_template
    import os
    from flask.ext.wtf import Form
    from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
    from wtforms.validators import Required
    from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap

    # App and DB config
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    app = Flask(__name__)
    bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    # classes
    class Role(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'roles'
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
        users = db.relationship('User', backref='role')

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<Role %r>' % self.name

    class User(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'users'
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
        role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<User %r>' % self.username

    class NameForm(Form):
        name = StringField('What is your name?',validators=[Required()])
        favorite = StringField('What is your favorite food?',validators=[Required()])
        submit = SubmitField('Submit')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever instructions you are following assume you have Flask-Script set up.  Your code does not, it's just written to run the app directly.  Install Flask-Script and modify your code to include the following parts then run the shell as described.

```
pip install flask-script
```

```
from flask_script import Manager

manager = Manager(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

```
$ python hello.py shell
>>> from hello import db
>>> db.create_all()
```